# I am trying to create a trigger in Apex which helps in increasing a count when a stage updates

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

Basically when Stage is marked as Closed Won, a number field in Opportunity labelled Closed_Won__c should increase its count by 1. Can someone help me with the code

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes please provide some code.

Comment: I am to to apex and i am unable to start. I would've provided the code if i knew what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you're new here. Start from Salesforce's Trailheads. They are great for people starting their journey with SF.

Here's a link for module about triggers:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

Although, I'd suggest you checking out other modules, starting with Apex Basics:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for that

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id,StageName FROM Opportunity Where Id IN :Trigger.New])
{
    if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won')
       {
           //add the code to increment the corresponding value here.
       }
}

}
```